# Anchor Transition conflicting with Bootstrap click function for Tabs

Tags: javascript, html, tabs, anchor, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to use a bootstrap tab click function but I'm having trouble with also using the animation for an anchor tag I got from stackoverflow. It seems like the on click function is messing up the on click function for the tab Is there a way around this?

```
<div id="tab1">
    <ul class="tab1-titles">
        <li class="active">
            <a href="#1a" data-toggle="tab">Tab1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#2a" data-toggle="tab">Tab2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="1a">
            <ul>
               <li>list-item-1</li>
               <li>list-item-2</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="2a">
            <ul>
               <li>list-item-1</li>
               <li>list-item-2</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
  if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
  var target = $(this.hash);
  target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
  if (target.length) {
    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: target.offset().top
    }, 1000);
    return false;
  }
}
});
});
```

Comment: why you have `return false;` in click event, that will stop event propagation. remove that and try

Comment: this worked but it caused a delay and flicker when I used the anchor tag

Answer (score 1):

instead of adding new `click` event handler, just use built-in tab change event like below

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e) {
    var hash = $(e.target).attr("href");

    //your code goes here
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
        var target = $(hash);
        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + hash.slice(1) + ']');
        if (target.length) {
            $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: target.offset().top
            }, 1000);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This can work but found another solution from co-worker thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had a co-worker look at it for me and he suggest of just adding a class to the anchor tag within this script. So I did and it works perfectly! I just had to make a more direct call for this function to work. He even added a offset scrolltop just in case you have a fixed header into the equation.

```
$('a[href^="#"].anchortargets:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
          var target = $(this.hash);
          target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
          if (target.length) {
            $('html,body').animate({
              scrollTop: parseInt(target.offset().top) - 140 + 'px'
            }, 500);
            return false;
          }
        }
      });
```